# How can I retrieve the field that is being summed in Pivot Table Values area using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Pivot Table. I can read the Row and Column values by iterating the PivotFields collection and checking the Orientation for Row and Column. What I can't find is the information pertaining to the DataField.

If I wanted to create a DataField using VBA, I could use code similar to the following to place a Field in the Values area of the PivotTable.

```
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        Call .AddDataField( .PivotFields("Sales"), _
                            "Sum of Sales", _
                            xlSum _
                          )
    End With
```

The above code is an example of creating a DataField only, showing the 3 pieces of information I need to be able to read out of a given PivotTable when I do not know how it was constructed.

In the example code above, how would I retrieve the Sales field from the PivotTable properties when I don't know it before hand? The Orientation is flagged as Hidden like all of the other unused but available Fields from the PivotTable Source Data.

The PivotTable has a DataPivotField property but I cannot find a list of its Fields anywhere.

Comment: Did you try `Dim pf As PivotField: Set pf = .AddDataField( .PivotFields("Sales"), "Sum of Sales", xlSum )`?

Comment: My question is how to I retrieve it later when I don't know what the field name is.

Comment: Maybe `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataFields("Sum of Sales")`.

Comment: Could someone elaborate on why the downvote? Not interested in arguing about it, but am just curious. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explore PivotFields in an unknown Workbook, you can use the code below:

```
Public Sub PrintPivotTablesOfThisWorkbook()
    Dim WS As Worksheet: For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        PrintPivotTablesOfWorksheet WS
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub PrintPivotTablesOfWorksheet(WS As Worksheet)
    Debug.Print "Worksheet named '" & WS.Name & "' has " & WS.PivotTables.Count & " PivotTables"
    Dim PT As PivotTable: For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
        Debug.Print "  PivotTable named '" & PT.Name & "' at " & PT.TableRange2.Address(False, False, xlA1, True)
        Debug.Print "    has " & PT.PageFields.Count & " PageFields:"
        Dim PF As PivotField: For Each PF In PT.PageFields
            Debug.Print "      PivotField named '" & PF.Name & "' " & GetSourceNameClause(PF)
        Next
        Debug.Print "    has " & PT.RowFields.Count & " RowFields:"
        Dim RF As PivotField: For Each RF In PT.RowFields
            Debug.Print "      PivotField named '" & RF.Name & "' " & GetSourceNameClause(RF)
        Next
        Debug.Print "    has " & PT.ColumnFields.Count & " ColumnFields:"
        Dim CF As PivotField: For Each CF In PT.ColumnFields
            Debug.Print "      PivotField named '" & CF.Name & "' " & GetSourceNameClause(CF)
        Next
        Debug.Print "    has " & PT.DataFields.Count & " DataFields:"
        Dim DF As PivotField: For Each DF In PT.DataFields
            Debug.Print "      PivotField named '" & DF.Name & "' " & GetSourceNameClause(DF) & " " & GetConsolidateFunctionClause(DF)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetSourceNameClause(Target As PivotField) As String
    Dim Result As String: Result = ""
    Dim SN As Variant: SN = GetSourceNameSafely(Target)
    If IsNull(SN) Then
        Result = "without a SourceName"
    Else
        Result = "with SourceName '" & SN & "'"
    End If
    GetSourceNameClause = Result
End Function

Public Function GetSourceNameSafely(Target As PivotField) As Variant
    Dim Result As Variant: Result = Null
    On Error Resume Next
        Result = Target.SourceName
    On Error GoTo 0
    GetSourceNameSafely = Result
End Function

Public Function GetConsolidateFunctionClause(Target As PivotField) As String
    Dim Result As String: Result = ""
    Dim FN As String: FN = GetConsolidationFunctionAsSring(Target.Function)
    If FN = "Invalid" Then
        Result = "without any Function"
    Else
        Result = "with Function " & FN
    End If
    GetConsolidateFunctionClause = Result
End Function

Public Function GetConsolidationFunctionAsSring(ConsolidationFunction As XlConsolidationFunction) As String
    Dim Result As String: Result = "Invalid"
    On Error Resume Next
        Select Case ConsolidationFunction
        Case xlAverage
            Result = "xlAverage"
        Case xlCount
            Result = "xlCount"
        Case xlCountNums
            Result = "xlCountNums"
        Case xlDistinctCount
            Result = "xlDistinctCount"
        Case xlMax
            Result = "xlMax"
        Case xlMin
            Result = "xlMin"
        Case xlProduct
            Result = "xlProduct"
        Case xlStDev
            Result = "xlStDev"
        Case xlStDevP
            Result = "xlStDevP"
        Case xlSum
            Result = "xlSum"
        Case xlUnknown
            Result = "xlUnknown"
        Case xlVar
            Result = "xlVar"
        Case xlVarP
            Result = "xlVarP"
        End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
    GetConsolidationFunctionAsSring = Result
End Function
```

After inserting the above into a Module; simply type `PrintPivotTablesOfThisWorkbook` in the Immediate Window, and it will enumerate all PivotTables in the workbook; or type `PrintPivotTablesOfWorksheet ActiveSheet` to list only PivotTables on the ActiveSheet.

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to find the object if you know the name before hand. But I want to be able to find it by reading the PivotTable properties.

I have made a little progress as shown by the code below. But neither the PivotItem or PivotField objects expose the Function correctly, which should be xlSum. In either object, the Function property is an error.

To simplify the code below, I used Item(1) in every case. In production code, I would have some kind of iteration logic as appropriate.

```
Dim oPivotTable As PivotTable
Dim oPivotField As PivotField
Dim oPivotItem As PivotItem

    Set oPivotTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Item(1)
    With oPivotTable
        With .DataPivotField.PivotItems
            Set oPivotItem = .Item(1)
            With oPivotItem
                Set oPivotField = oPivotTable.PivotFields.Item(oPivotItem.Name)
            End With
        End With
    End With
```

I finally found it! `oPivotItem.DataRange.PivotField.Function` returns the correct value. Also, `oPivotItem.DataRange.PivotField.SourceName` returns the Field name.

So, from the original post, the 3 associated values are

```
    1. oPivotItem.DataRange.PivotField.SourceName, 
    2. oPivotItem.Name and
    3. oPivotItem.DataRange.PivotField.Function
```

Comment: You did not mention in your post that you don't know the name, actually the name was in the code you included. I think the verb "enumerate" would be better than "find" in this situation (as far as I understand what you wrote).

Comment: The code you posted works only if you add "Sum of Sales" first: `Set oPivotItem = .Item(1)`.

Comment: Things like `Set oPivotTable = Nothing` are superfluous.

Comment: @z32a7ul I respectfully disagree. If the Values exist, then I read the values for Item(1) and the 3 items I posted last in this code will contain the values used to create the DataField. You should be able to paste the code into any module and hook it to a PivotTable to read the values.

Comment: The code you posted is totally convoluted and not reusable at all. It defines a variable, which boils down to this if you resolve the three (!) `With` statements: `oPivotField = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Item(1).PivotFields.Item(ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Item(1).DataPivotField.PivotItems.Item(1).Name)` and that is not used later for anything.

Comment: Your conclusion is that `oPivotItem = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Item(1).DataPivotField.PivotItems.Item(1)` can be used to access its three properties, `oPivotItem.DataRange.PivotField.SourceName`, `oPivotItem.Name` and `oPivotItem.DataRange.PivotField.Function`. This is true but an extremly overcomplicated approach that makes no sense in practice. ...

Comment: ... You can either save the return value of `.AddDataField` as I proposed in my first comment (using your names `Set oPivotItem = .AddDataField( .PivotFields("Sales"), "Sum of Sales", xlSum )`) or you can reference everything by their name (`Set oPivotItem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataFields("Sum of Sales")`). These two have the same three properties ("values" as you call them) but are easy to understand and have real life use cases.

Comment: If you add a line like `Call .AddDataField(.PivotFields("Costs"), "Sum of Costs", xlSum)` (assuming you have a `Costs` field), then you won't be able to retrieve the Sales field the way you proposed as it will be `.PivotItems.Item(2)` instead of `.PivotItems.Item(1)`.

Comment: @z32a7ul Sorry for the confusion. I've attempted to clarify what I was asking in the original post as well as the answer I posted. To keep code simpler, I used Item(1) to illustrate things. In production code you would iterate to avoid the situation you noted, where the actual value might not be Item(1). In the case that sparked my question, I inherited an Excel file that had numerous sheets with similar PivotTables and I was trying to iterate them and list Rows, Columns and DataFields. I appreciate your help. Should you wish to post some sample code, I would be interested to see it.

Comment: @z32a7ul You called my sample code convoluted. I would be interested in your code to read the Rows, Column and DataFields out of a PivotTable's properties. You are highly rated and I appreciate the interaction.